# Connecting sets of pc fans to a 12v battery

Tags: power-electronics, battery-operated

I am very new to electronics so please understand. I have researched but need clarity.

Basically I need to create a mock intake/outake exhaust system using recycled pc fans. Now I have to power it with a 12v 200AH battery. Basically to adapt it to the fans I can use old recycled phone adapters. However my issue is that their intake voltage is 100-240V @ 0.35-1A dependant on the adapter.

Could someone possibly give me an idea as to how to go about this? I know ideally I would need to up the voltage and lower the amperage for the intake into the adapter but my resources are extremely limited. I have to salvage all of my parts from old electronics.

I do happen to have parts from an old inverter so could salvage parts from there too.

List of parts to look out for is also welcome. I am new to this but I am learning slowly.

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't the PC fans 12V already?

Comment: `Could someone possibly give me an idea as to how to go about this?` ... how to go about what? ... you have not fully described what you are trying to do ... all we know is that you are trying to connect unknown fans to a 12 V battery and that 100-240 V, is involved somehow (assuming AC voltage) .... please add info about the fans, from the labels on the fans ... please explain what is the purpose of the 100-240 V

Comment: @jsotola , if you read everything you will have all the information you need. Perhaps not the amperage of the pc fans but everything else should be sufficient as per what I can see. I figured out an alternative solution though but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the fans are PC fans that typically means either 12V or 5V fans. Since you are talking about phone adapters, I'm assuming you are looking at 5V fans.

Don't use a house phone adapter, which is a 100 to 240 V AC to 5V DC (probably) voltage regulator. Use a car usb adapter for a cheap 12V to 5V voltage regulator.

For 12V fans just connect them directly to the battery.

I hope you have a voltage monitor and cut off circuit so you don't over drain the 12 V battery.

Comment: Could I just use an old digital solar charger as a voltage monitor?

Comment: Not sure how that solar charger works. Does it cut off the output if the battery goes under a certain voltage level?

Comment: Use a solar charge controller with _three_ ports: One port is for the solar panels. If you don't have solar panels, then just leave that port unconnected. One port is for the battery, and the third port is for the load (i.e., the fans.) The charge controller should shut off the "load" port when the voltage on the battery port drops down to some threshold value (typically between 10.5 and 11 volts). Using a solar controller with no solar panels might be bit of overkill, but it could be less costly than designing and building your own circuit if you don't already have the tools and experience.

Comment: @SolomonSlow pretty much the situation with regards to the tools and experience. Will do, thanks :)